# Connect to a remote dockerized MongoDB replica set

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

In my remote machine, I've set up a docker container machine that I manage using docker-compose. 
I created 3 docker containers for each MongoDB instance I want in my replica set

```
mongodb_01:
    image: mvertes/alpine-mongo
    entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10001:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/01:/data/db

mongodb_02:
    image: mvertes/alpine-mongo
    entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
    restart: always
    depends_on:
       - mongodb_01
    ports:
      - 10002:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/02:/data/db

mongodb_03:
    image: mvertes/alpine-mongo
    entrypoint: ['/usr/bin/mongod', '--bind_ip_all', '--replSet', 'rs0']
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_02
    ports:
      - 10003:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/03:/data/db
```

I also configured the replica set. and this is an excerpt:

```
"_id" : "rs0",
...
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "mongodb_01:27017",
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "mongodb_02:27017",
        ...
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "mongodb_03:27017",
        ...
    }
],
...
}
```

Everything works fine, and intra-communications between other docker images and this replica set works fine using the connection string

```
mongodb://mongodb_01:27017,mongodb_02:27017,mongodb_03:27017/<database>?replicaSet=rs0
```

The problem is when I need to connect a remote client to this replica set.
For example, using mongoose via node on my dev machine I get:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb_02:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb_02 mongodb_02:27017]
```

Sometimes it fails on mongodb_03.

**Edit**: as pointed out, here's my connection string from remote machine:

```
mongodb://<remote-host>:10001,<remote-host>:10002,<remote-host>:10003/<database>?replicaSet=rs0
```

**Edit 2**: using a client like Mongodb Compass I can successfully connect to the single instances correctly. When I add the replicaset, i got the error.
So I tried to create a dummy container with mongodb (using mongo:latest).

```
$ docker run -it mongo:latest bash
```

and running

```
mongo mongodb://<remote-host>:10001,<remote-host>:10002,<remote-host>:10003/<database>?replicaSet=rs0
```

I get

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://<remote-host>:10001,<remote-host>:10002,<remote-host>:10003/<database>?gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=rs0
2019-03-04T16:12:54.375+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for rs0/<remote-host>:10001,<remote-host>:10002,<remote-host>:10003
2019-03-04T16:12:54.377+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to <remote-host>:10003 (1 connections now open to <remote-host>:10003 with a 5 second timeout)
2019-03-04T16:12:54.377+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to <remote-host>:10001 (1 connections now open to <remote-host>:10001 with a 5 second timeout)
2019-03-04T16:12:54.378+0000 I NETWORK  [js] changing hosts to rs0/mongodb_01:27017,mongodb_02:27017,mongodb_03:27017 from rs0/<remote-host>:10001,<remote-host>:10002,<remote-host>:10003
2019-03-04T16:12:54.882+0000 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set rs0
2019-03-04T16:12:54.882+0000 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
```

and so on.

Thanks for any help and suggestion !

Comment: Can you please confirm the error message ? Is the current error message what you already got ?

Comment: Also the ports in the connection string are different from the ones in  docker-compose

Comment: @MostafaHussein yes, I tried with a node.js app and I got the same error, this time pointing out it cannot find mongodb_03

Comment: @MostafaHussein sorry, I edited the question modifying the ports in the docker-compose to the right ones

Comment: Can you add this to your `/etc/hosts` ? `<remote-host> mongodb_XX mongodb_XX mongodb_XX` and test it

Comment: Added to /etc/hosts as requested. Error remains. Seems to be some misconfiguration on remote when resolving externally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced exactly same problem with you, and I've figured out it.

It is because that your remote client does not know 'mongo1:27017' host. It's is just used inside docker network only.

It is a bit tricky to explain how I've solved this problem. I'll show my docker-compose.yml first.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mongo-primary:
    container_name: mongo-primary
    hostname: mongo-primary
    image: mongo:4.0.11
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/primary/data/db:/data/db
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/keyfile:/data/keyfile
    extra_hosts:
      - "address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:192.168.1.xx"
    networks:
      - mongo-cluster
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: changeme
    command: --bind_ip_all --auth --keyFile /data/keyfile/mongo-cluster-key --replSet rs0 --enableMajorityReadConcern false
  mongo-secondary:
    container_name: mongo-secondary
    hostname: mongo-secondary
    image: mongo:4.0.11
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/secondary/data/db:/data/db
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/keyfile:/data/keyfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo-primary
    extra_hosts:
      - ""address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:192.168.1.xx""
    networks:
      - mongo-cluster
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    command: --bind_ip_all -auth --keyFile /data/keyfile/mongo-cluster-key --replSet rs0 --enableMajorityReadConcern false
  mongo-arbiter:
    container_name: mongo-arbiter
    hostname: mongo-arbiter
    image: mongo:4.0.11
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/arbiter/data/arb:/data/arb
      - $HOME/.dockerMongoRepl/keyfile:/data/keyfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo-primary
    extra_hosts:
      - ""address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:192.168.1.xx""
    networks:
      - mongo-cluster
    ports:
      - 27019:27017
    restart: always
    command: --bind_ip_all --auth --keyFile /data/keyfile/mongo-cluster-key --replSet rs0 --enableMajorityReadConcern false

networks:
  mongo-cluster:
```

!Important part is 'extra_hosts'!! It can make containers access to host computer.

"address.WhichCanAccess.yourServer" <- in my case, my asus router has been set with asus ddns, so it will be XXX.asuscomm.com

"192.168.1.xx" <- IP addres which asus router has assigned the host computer

Maybe some configuration of those compose file are not required.

Run 3 containers with docker-compose.

Next, enter the primary's mongo shell, set replica like below

```
config = {
  "_id": "rs0",
  "members": [{
    "_id": 0,
    "host": "address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:27017"
  }, {
    "_id": 1,
    "host": "address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:27018"
  }, {
    "_id": 2,
    "host": "address.whichCanAccess.yourServer:27019",
    arbiterOnly: true
  }]
}

rs.initiate(config)
```

In this way, mongo containers will communicate each other through docker's host network, and it can be accessed from remote IP.

Comment: Yup it's tricky, but it can work. I moved to atlas and i'm planning to move to a serverless platform in the near future. But thanks for sharing your experience

Comment: The link you shared forward to some kind of scam link now.

Comment: It worked for me, however for a team this is not an ideal solution since every team member will have to be updating hosts... Below I've posted a localhost based solution that is basically a variation of yours but will not require hosts updates.

Comment: Hi @trainto, May i know how your /etc/hosts file looks like? I am trying your solution on ubuntu 18.04 but i couldn't initialize replica set with ip-address of my host machine.

Comment: @user3792685 Hi, I've moved my mongo cluster to cloud, so I don't use those settings anymore, but when I tried that settings, I didn't touch /etc/hosts file.
I used asus router and its ddns service, then set port forwarding configuration for each port like 27017, 27018, 27019 to the server where mongo cluster configured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localhost for this purpose. The compose will roughly look like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.11
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    extra_hosts:
      - "localhost:0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - "./lambda/docker/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf"
```

Then when initializing replicaset, make sure to set your host to localhost. Example:

```
{
    // ........
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "localhost:27017"
            // .........
        }
    ]
    // ...........
}
```

Tested on OSX. On linux/windows it may potentially have different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the post. When I initialized rs my hosts were `mongo-1:27017`, `mongo-2:27017`, and `mongo-3:27017`. Now, I'd need to reconfig it to `localhost:27017`, but it says `Found two member configurations with same host field, members.0.host == members.1.host == localhost:27017`. Also, cannot set different port since Mongo official image exposed port 27017. I'd need to create my own image. Any tips?

Comment: yeah, this is actually quite interesting. I use this config to mostly have a single mongo node configured to act as a replicaset locally. Ports should be easy to workaround by remaping them within your compose file, however, hosts may be more challenging. I would add few more localhost aliases to hosts file like 1.localhost, 2.localhost, 3.localhost and then use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out this by using "2030:2030" (e.g.) in `ports` in `docker-compose.yml` and then `--port 2030` + changing `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a free version of Atlas for test and integration. Once the my work is complete, I'll use my own replica set on my servers.

That's a bit of a hassle, and I need to triple check everything before production without the support of dev tools and debuggers.