# Cannot connect with Mongo Compass to docerized mongoDB replica sets

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongodb-compass

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongo_launcher:
        container_name: mongo_launcher
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - mongo_network
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mongo-setup.sh:/scripts/mongo-setup.sh
        entrypoint: ['sh', '/scripts/mongo-setup.sh']
    mongo_replica_1:
        container_name: mongo_replica_1
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27017',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network
    mongo_replica_2:
        container_name: mongo_replica_2
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27018:27018
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27018',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network
    mongo_replica_3:
        container_name: mongo_replica_3
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27019:27019
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27019',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network

networks:
    mongo_network:
        driver: bridge
```

Note that the first service will use the `mongo-setup.sh` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB_REPLICA_1=mongo_replica_1
MONGODB_REPLICA_2=mongo_replica_2
MONGODB_REPLICA_3=mongo_replica_3

echo "************ [ Waiting for startup ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

until curl http://${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo "************ [ Startup completed ] **************" ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}

mongosh --host ${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017 <<EOF
var cfg = {
    "_id": "dbrs",
    "protocolVersion": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017",
            "priority": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_2}:27018",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "host": "${MONGODB_REPLICA_3}:27019",
            "priority": 1
        }
    ],settings: {chainingAllowed: true}
};
rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
rs.secondaryOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
db.getMongo().setSecondaryOk(); 
EOF
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d`, it succeeds and when I run `docker ps` I get:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                 NAMES
0c8f6d916e4a   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   11 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27018->27018/tcp   mongo_replica_2
c59cb625362e   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   11 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp              mongo_replica_1
cb61093e4dd0   mongo:5.0.8   "/usr/bin/mongod --b…"   11 seconds ago   Up 10 seconds   27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27019->27019/tcp   mongo_replica_3
```

But when I try to connect one of the replica sets with Mongo Compass I get the following error:
[image]

So it seems as the containers are all running fine, why do I get this issue? Please advice..

---

I could solve the issue by appending the following content to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_1
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_2
127.0.0.1 mongo_replica_3
```

Could anyone come up with more elegant way?

---

I tried to bypass the `/etc/hosts` solution, so I edited `docker-compose.yaml` file and I applied `extra_hosts`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    mongo_launcher:
        container_name: mongo_launcher
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        restart: on-failure
        networks:
            - mongo_network
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mongo-setup.sh:/scripts/mongo-setup.sh
        entrypoint: ['sh', '/scripts/mongo-setup.sh']
    mongo_replica_1:
        container_name: mongo_replica_1
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        extra_hosts:
            - 'localhost:0.0.0.0'
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27017',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica1/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network
    mongo_replica_2:
        container_name: mongo_replica_2
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27018:27018
        extra_hosts:
            - 'localhost:0.0.0.0'
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27018',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica2/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network
    mongo_replica_3:
        container_name: mongo_replica_3
        image: mongo:5.0.8
        ports:
            - 27019:27019
        extra_hosts:
            - 'localhost:0.0.0.0'
        restart: always
        entrypoint:
            [
                '/usr/bin/mongod',
                '--bind_ip_all',
                '--replSet',
                'dbrs',
                '--dbpath',
                '/data/db',
                '--port',
                '27019',
            ]
        volumes:
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3:/data/db
            - ./.volumes/mongo/replica3/configdb:/data/configdb
        networks:
            - mongo_network

networks:
    mongo_network:
        driver: bridge
```

Then I edited the `mongo-setup.sh` to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "************ [ Waiting for startup ] **************"

until curl http://${MONGODB_REPLICA_1}:27017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo "************ [ Startup completed ] **************"

mongosh --host localhost:27017 <<EOF
var cfg = {
    "_id": "dbrs",
    "protocolVersion": 1,
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "localhost:27017",
            "priority": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "host": "localhost:27018",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "host": "localhost:27019",
            "priority": 1
        }
    ],settings: {chainingAllowed: true}
};
rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
rs.secondaryOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
db.getMongo().setSecondaryOk(); 
EOF
```

**And I removed the edits I made in `/etc/hosts` file. I don't get an error like before, I do get timeout:**

[image]

Comment: Probably it is related to different ports in rs configuration `mongo2:27017` and published port 27022. Compass tries to connect to `mongo2:27017` and can't connect to 27017 or resolve mongo2 address.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten
Might be. I edited some configuration, please take an another glance

Comment: I believe that you have the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986570/connect-to-a-remote-dockerized-mongodb-replica-set

Comment: @ExplodingKitten

I tried, didn't work for me. I edited my Q with the try.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is the appropriate solution for you, but actually, you can use your first bash file and provide IP address of your host (eg. 192.168.1.2) as a value for `MONGODB_REPLICA_1/2/3`. So, when Compass tries to connect to rs, it will be able to reach each instance.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten
It is not scalable solution as IP Host may change and other programmers have different IP.